# There are two types:String and List<Object> in JsonArray ,How to deal with Google Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

JSON string:

```
{
    "vcardArray": [
        "vcard",
        [
            [
                "version",
                {},
                "text",
                "4.0"
            ],
            [
                "fn",
                {},
                "text",
                "Focus IP, dba AppDetex"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Invalid json string

Comment: My mistake! I have put it right!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Arraylist<Arraylist<Object>>` since you have different types.